# How to give folder path of a s3 bucket directory in a S3KeySensorOperator Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Current Scenario :This is my S3KeySensor operator. Now I have tired it and used it and it works fine

```
 s3KeySensor = S3KeySensor(task_id='Check_file_in_s3_{}'.format(country),
                    bucket_key='*.csv',
                    wildcard_match=True,
                    bucket_name='s3sensorbucket,
                    aws_conn_id='my_s3_conn',
                    timeout=18 * 60 * 60,
                    poke_interval=10,
                    soft_fail=True,
                    default_args=default_args
                              )
```

ERROR:

```
 Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching 
the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:]. 
[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA- 
Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}
```

Desired output : I want my output to look like this so that I can give my folder name in the bucket so the s3KeySensor can go and look at the location and proceed with yes or no. I tried Prefix option but it says it doesn't have function name prefix.
Help me how can I fix it?

```
s3KeySensor = S3KeySensor(task_id='Check_file_in_s3_{}'.format(country),
                    bucket_key='*.csv',
                    wildcard_match=True,
                    bucket_name='s3sensorbucket/glueProcessed_ke_{}'.format(country),
                    aws_conn_id='my_s3_conn',
                    timeout=18 * 60 * 60,
                    poke_interval=10,
                    soft_fail=True,
                    default_args=default_args
                              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `bucket_key` instead of `bucket_name`. From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3_key/index.html#module-airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3_key):

> bucket_key (str) -- The key being waited on. Supports full s3:// style url or relative path from root level. When it's specified as a full s3:// url, please leave bucket_name as None.

> bucket_name (str) -- Name of the S3 bucket. Only needed when bucket_key is not provided as a full s3:// url.

```py
s3KeySensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id="Check_file_in_s3_{}".format(country),
    bucket_key=f"s3://s3tosensorbucketname/glueProcessed_ke_{country}/*.csv",
    wildcard_match=True,
    aws_conn_id="my_s3_conn",
    timeout=18 * 60 * 60,
    poke_interval=10,
    soft_fail=True,
)
```

Or if you want to use `bucket_name` do:

```py
s3KeySensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id="Check_file_in_s3_{}".format(country),
    bucket_key=f"glueProcessed_ke_{country}/*.csv",
    bucket_name="s3sensorbucketname",
    wildcard_match=True,
    aws_conn_id="my_s3_conn",
    timeout=18 * 60 * 60,
    poke_interval=10,
    soft_fail=True,
)
```

Comment: okay let me try and get back to you on this . Thanks for the help tho .Hopefully it works

Comment: @NIicoE , thanks it worked for me. Appreciate your input

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thanks for the feedback